# projection map is flat

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> Let a ring $A = A_1\times A_2$. Then the projection map $A\to A_1$ is flat.

All the rings above are commutative ring with unity. I want to show this by showing if two $A$-modules $\phi:N'\to N$ is injective, then $\psi:A_1\otimes_A N'\to A_1\otimes_A N$ is injective. Let $a_1\otimes n'\in A_1\otimes N'$ such that $\psi(a_1\otimes n') = 0\iff a_1\otimes\phi(n')=0\iff a_1\cdot 1\otimes\phi(n') = 0\iff (a_1,a_2)(1\otimes \phi(n'))=0$ for any $a_2\in A_2$. How can I proceed further?

Comment: I don't know enough about tensor-products to say whether this direct computation approach is the easiest/would work out, but I think another idea would be to show that $A_1$ is a projective $A$-module (remember that projective modules are exactly those that are direct summands of free modules)

Comment: @leoli1 That's one way. Thanks. funny thing is, the above example appeared before the book introduce the projective module

Comment: Without using the 'projective-property' explicitely we could argue as follows (this is more or less the projective argument in disguise): Note that if $M\to M',N\to N'$ are maps then they are both injective iff $M\oplus M'\to N\oplus N'$ is injective. Now 'add' the maps $A_1\otimes_AN'\to A_1\otimes_AN$ and $A_2\otimes_AN'\to A_2\otimes_AN$ and see what we get.